# n_distinct(x) and length(unique(x)) doesn't work in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to render t.test and ANOVA results reactively.

I found that `length(unique(x))` or `n_distinct(x)` does not work in shiny server section.

Here are my codes.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "testpage"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("file-csv")),
        menuItem("descrptive", tabName = "widget1", icon = icon("chart-bar"))
        )
      ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "data",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 6, height=200, title ="file", 
                    fileInput("file0","select a file", buttonLabel = "select", accept = c(".csv")),
                    DTOutput('dt')),
                
              )),
      tabItem(tabName = "widget1",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 4, title = "Variances",
                    selectInput(
                      "sel","methods", c("prop","mean")
                    ),
                    selectizeInput(
                      'a', 'group', choices = colnames(file),
                      options = list(
                        placeholder = 'Please select a variable below',
                        onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                      )),
                    conditionalPanel(
                      condition = "input.sel == 'mean' ",
                      selectizeInput(
                        'b', 'vector', choices = colnames(file), multiple =T,
                        options = list(
                          placeholder = 'Please select a variable below',
                          onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                        )
                      )
                      
                    ),
                 
                box(
                  width = 8, title = "results",
                    dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
                  dataTableOutput("tbl2")
                  ),
                
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "p.value",
                    actionButton("go","tests"),
                    uiOutput("results")

                ),
                
              )
      )
    )
  )
)    

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.table::fread(input$file0$datapath)
  })

  output$dt <- DT::renderDT({
    req(input$file0)
    data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file0, {
    mytable <- read.csv(input$file0$datapath) %>% as_tibble()
    req(mytable)
    updateSelectInput(session, "a", label = "group", choices = colnames(mytable))
    updateSelectInput(session, "b", label = "vector", choices = colnames(mytable))
    updateSelectInput(session, "x", label = "X Variable", choices = colnames(mytable))
    updateSelectInput(session, "y", label = "Y Variable", choices = colnames(mytable))
    updateSelectInput(session, "z", label = "Z Variable", choices = colnames(mytable))
  })
  
  
# prop -----------------------------
  proptable <- reactive({
    data() %>% 
      filter(!is.na(input$a)) %>% 
               group_by_(input$a) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(percentage = round(n/sum(n)*100,1))
  })
  
  
  output$tbl1 <- renderDataTable(extensions = "Buttons",
                                 options = list(dom = "Bfrtip",
                                                buttons = "copy"),{
                                                  validate(
                                                    need(input$a !="", message = "select variables.")
                                                  )
                                                  if(input$sel == "prop")
                                                    proptable()
  })    
 

# mean ------------------------------------------
  meantable <- reactive({
    data() %>% filter(!is.na(input$a)) %>% 
      group_by_at(input$a) %>% 
      summarise_at(vars(input$b), funs(round(mean(., na.rm = T), digits = 2)))
  })
  
  output$tbl2 <- renderDataTable(extensions = "Buttons",
                                 options = list(dom = "Bfrtip",
                                                buttons = "copy"),{
                                                  if(input$sel == "mean")
                                                    meantable()
    })
  
  myeval=function(text){
    eval(parse(text=text))
  }
  
  # tests --------------------------

  output$results<- renderUI({
    input$go
    
    isolate({
      for(i in seq_along(input$b)){
        local({
          j<-i
          rstname <- paste0("result",j)
          output[[rstname]]=renderPrint({
            if(length(unique(input$a, na.rm = T))>2)
              {
              formul = paste0(input$b[j],"~",input$a)
              fm = myeval(formul)
              anova(lm(fm, data= data()))
              }
            else if(length(unique(input$a, na.rm=T))>2){
              x <- t.test(fm2, data= data())
              x$p.value}
         

            })
        })
      }
      
      rstlist <- lapply(1:length(input$b),function(i){
        rstname <- paste0("result",i)
        verbatimTextOutput(rstname)
      })
      
      do.call(tagList, rstlist)
    })
  })
```

I tried to figure out the problem, using `observeEvent`, realized that `length(unique(x))` or `n_distinct(x)` keeps showing the results like so.

```
    observeEvent(input$go,{
  cat("n_distinct of", input$a, "is", length(unique((data[,"input$a"]), na.rm=T)), ".\n")
})

  n_distinct of ee_a is ee_a . ##results
```

Would you mind if help me fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Do they work correctly on the console? (2) Is there really a column in `data` named `"input$a"`? That is a static string, btw, not a quoted reference to the shiny object `input$a`. (3) What does `data` look like to you? (4) Ultimately, please make this question reproducible.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comment. I revised my question reproducible.